# Program to check whether two trees are duplicates or not

Tags: java, tree

I am having trouble with a method that checks whether two trees are duplicates or not. It seems that everytime it returns "Not Duplicates" even though both trees contain the same things. I will include the duplicateCheck method and my main method. I don't know where the code is incorrect, or if the problem is in my main method and the declaration of both trees.

```
public boolean duplicateCheck(BinarySearchTree otherTree)
{
        return duplicateCheck(this.root, otherTree.getRoot());
}

  protected boolean duplicateCheck(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2)
{
        if ((t1 == null) && (t2 == null))
        return true;


        else if (countNodes(t1) != countNodes(t2))
        return false;

        else {

        KeyedItem key1 = (KeyedItem) t1.getItem();
        KeyedItem key2 = (KeyedItem) t2.getItem();
        String s1 = (String) key1.getKey();
        String s2 = (String) key2.getKey();

        if (! s1.equals(s2) )
        return false;

        else
        return (duplicateCheck(t1.getLeft(), t2.getLeft()) && duplicateCheck(t1.getRight(), t2.getRight()) );
}
}

import java.util.*;

public class MyTree
{
        public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException
        {

        BinarySearchTree t1 = new BinarySearchTree();

        t1.insert(new KeyedItem("M"));
        t1.insert(new KeyedItem("J"));
        t1.insert(new KeyedItem("D"));
        t1.insert(new KeyedItem("F"));
        t1.insert(new KeyedItem("L"));
        t1.insert(new KeyedItem("W"));
        t1.insert(new KeyedItem("S"));
        t1.insert(new KeyedItem("T"));
        t1.insert(new KeyedItem("Z"));


        BinarySearchTree t2 = (BinarySearchTree) t1.clone();

        t2.insert(new KeyedItem("M"));
        t2.insert(new KeyedItem("J"));
        t2.insert(new KeyedItem("D"));
        t2.insert(new KeyedItem("F"));
        t2.insert(new KeyedItem("L"));
        t2.insert(new KeyedItem("W"));
        t2.insert(new KeyedItem("S"));
        t2.insert(new KeyedItem("T"));
        t2.insert(new KeyedItem("Z"));


        if (t1.duplicateCheck(t2))
                System.out.println("Duplicates");
        else
                System.out.println("Not Duplicates");



}
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like you put everything in `t2` twice.  I'd expect it to be different from `t1`.

Comment: You are presumably referring to the use of t1.clone() followed by a bunch of inserts.

Comment: Yes, OP is copying the entire tree, and THEN inserting all the elements a second time.

Answer (score 0):

In general the best way to resolve these sorts of issues is to write unit tests to ensure each method does exactly what you expect and then, if you still can't find the issue, use an interactive debugger. I suspect you would find your issue very quickly with this approach and they are skills you will need in any case.

There are quite a few issues with your code

1. You are cloning t1 when you create t2. If you are trying to test your method you should create it as a new tree (i.e. `new BinarySearchTree()`). `clone` is a method that should be used in very specific circumstances only (if at all).
2. You are checking if both t1 and t2 are null but you aren't checking each individually. Unless `countNodes` catches this issue you'll get a NPE on `getItem`.
3. The extensive use of casting should not be necessary. Either `BinarySearchTree` should be generic or the getters should be returning the correct type.